# Close window popup after successfully submit form and refresh background form

Tags: blocks, magento2.4.5, popup, product-grid, action

I've added window model popup in block grid using add coulmnn method.

this popup is loaded when admin user click on action column. this popup window render as below approch.

```
$this->getColumn()->setActions([
            [
                'caption' => __('Marketing Form'),
                'url' => $url,
                'field' => 'id',
                'popup' => true 
            ]
        ]);
```

Model POPup window
[image]

I have a form using UI element on that popup but now I want to close this window popup and refresh the background page, can anyone help me?

Comment: I have added the javascript and below peace of code close the child window and refresh the parent window.

opener.location.reload(); // or opener.location.href = opener.location.href;
window.close(); // or self.close();